# Ubuntu on a home built computer cant find live file medium

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

Ive been trying to get Ubuntu to work on my pc but everytime i hit try without installing or install it always ends up at a busybox screen and says  "Unable to find a medium with a live file system." Ive tried every work around i can find and every fix i can find but no matter what it always comes up as that. My pc is as such:
Windows 8.1
AMD A6-3650 Overclocked to 4.1GHz
Asus F1A55-M LE motherboard
EVGA GTX650 Ti graphics card
8GBs RAM
Western Digital Green 500GB hard drive

I did a 1GB partition to the hard drive and tried to install it on the partition and got nothing. Ive been using a thumbdrive with a "bootable" Ubuntu 12.04. Is anybody albe to help?

Answer (score 0):

I also had problem booting up a live cd so I installed my Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Win 8 using WUBI. I consider this an improvement over Mint and Ubuntu installed in it's own partition.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer

Comment: Ive tried that and it installs. But just like before windows will start and tell me it failed to start due to a file missing and then asks if i want ubuntu or windows 8.1. if i hit ubuntu its an endless loop of the previous problem. if i select windows 8.1 it will boot to windows without an issue